# capture part of url with regex

Tags: regex

Ok I promise I'll learn regular expressions tonight but right now I need a quick fix.
(Really, I swear I will!)

How do I extract the value of what comes after name= this url:

page?id=1&name=hello

In this case I would be trying to isolate 'hello'.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the language. What language and RegEx client are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most engines:

```
[\&\?]name\=(.*?)(?:&|$)
```

You've got it in $1.

Comment: You don't need to escape & and ? inside character classes, = doesn't need escaping at all and the part after the = could probably be written as ([^&]*) to avoid the lookahead.

Comment: There is no lookahead, just a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

What language are you using? Pretty much every language has a utility that will do this for you so you don't have to resort to regex:

**PHP**:

```
parse_str(parse_url('page?id=1&name=hello', PHP_URL_QUERY), $query);
print $query['name']; // outputs hello
```

**Python**:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> from cgi import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(urlparse('page?id=1&name=hello').query)
{'id': ['1'], 'name': ['hello']}
```

Comment: Yeah I know! But I'm using regex for mod_rewrite :-(

Comment: Ah. I guess I'll leave this here anyways.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I always appreciate your responses.